# Find the value of the given limit

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Find the value of this limit:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int _0^\infty \cos\left(\dfrac{t^3}{3}+tx\right) dt$$.

Now as $x\to \infty \implies \dfrac{t^3}{3}+tx\to \infty  $ for any fixed $t$.

then   $\cos\left(\dfrac{t^3}{3}+tx\right)$ is oscillating

Now I dont understand how should I compute the limit in this case?

Can someone please help.

Comment: Have you checked if the integral if finite for fixed $x$?. To me this looks doubtful.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I believe finiteness should follow from the following argument, (though I don't have time to check my work right now): $$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+tx\right)dt\right| &= \left|\int_0^{\infty}\cos(t^3/3)\cos(tx)dt - \int_0^{\infty}\sin(t^3/3)\sin(tx)dt\right|
\\& \le \int_0^{\infty}\left|\cos(t^3/3)\cos(tx)\right|dt + \int_0^{\infty}\left|\sin(t^3/3)\sin(tx)\right|dt
\\&\le \int_0^{\infty} |\cos(t^3/3)|dt + \int_0^{\infty}|\sin(t^3/3)|dt
\\&= \frac{\Gamma(1/3)}{2\sqrt{3}} + \frac{\Gamma(1/3)}{6}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you very much.

Comment: Having a look at [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) may be useful.

Comment: @KemonoChen;I checked it but it does not give a proof why the integral converges to 0

Comment: "A more accurate formula for Ai(z) and a formula for Bi(z) when π/3 < |arg(z)| < π or, equivalently, for Ai(−z) and Bi(−z) when |arg(z)| < 2π/3 but not zero, are:[3]"$$\operatorname{Ai}(-z)=\frac{\sin\cdots}{z^{1/4}\sqrt\pi}$$

Comment: @KemonoChen;Can you help to show that the integral converges

Comment: Substitute $u=t^3$ and apply Dirichlet's test.

Comment: @KemonoChen; But how to find the value of the limit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86131/discussion-between-kemono-chen-and-join-phd).

Comment: Take a look at the [Riemann–Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Lebesgue_lemma). (hint: the limit is 0)